# Magento 2.0 CE recurring profile support

Tags: magento2

Have Magento 2.0 CE dropped support for recurring profile products?

I couldn't find anything about recurring profile in a recently created demo store neither in the documentation.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurring profiles were removed from Magento 2 in version [0.1.0-alpha108](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/d50ee54/CHANGELOG.md#010-alpha108) released in December 2014.

I haven't seen any public discussion of the change, however in a presentation by Alan Kent (Chief Architect of Magento), [a slide titled "Modularity"](http://www.slideshare.net/MeetMagentoNY2014/mmny14-alan-kent-m2-overview/21) does mention extracting recurring payments. So possibly the plan is to add the function as a module at a later time, or to let the marketplace fill the need.

Answer (score 0):

Just for further readers.

It looks like the Recurring Profile functionality was finally moved to a separate module in 2.0.0.0-dev65 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/d50ee54/CHANGELOG.md#2000-dev65) - See Modularity improvements.